# Make table control align to display width?

Tags: sap-gui, dynpro, s4hana

I can't figure out how to make my transactions fill the full width of my monitor, the width appears to be fixed, and I've got a horizontal scroll bar.

The screenshot below is from transaction `ME21N`, in S/4HANA, running on SAP GUI client 770, to illustrate the issue.

There's over 50% of my screen unused, which would be super-useful for this t-code and many others.

Does anyone know what I need to do to "fix" this?

I have tried all the available themes, and can't seem to find any setting to modify this.

[image: SAP GUI ME21N]

Thank-you in advance! :)

Comment: You can't change [that](https://www.samplecodeabap.com/screen-size-display-alv-grid-fullscreen-sap-abap/)

Comment: That's one of the reasons why SAP has been abandoning SAP GUI (very old technology) for years and people are now using Fiori (Web)... If you're tired of that space, you may press Windows + Left or Right keys to make the window occupy half your screen (and Up key to occupy full screen).

Comment: Thank-you both! I believe we've plans to transition to Fiori in the near future. I'll hold out for that, and the Windows+Left/Right trick.

Comment: In case someone looks at your question to get a solution for having data with full width using the old ABAP/SAP GUI/Dynpro technology, this can be solved partially by using Control Framework and the magical full size container `cl_gui_container=>screen0`. It's complex to explain but the Web contains examples. Alas, it needs using Controls all over the place, e.g. `cl_gui_alv_grid` for grid views, `cl_gui_html_viewer` for texts and input fields, so it requires a lot of knowledge which is maybe not worth learning (better go to newest technology Fiori/SAPUI5).